# display inline-block not working on p element inside flex-container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make the 'p' element's size be it's own content size.

the 'p' element is inside a flex-container so for some reason setting the display to inline-block isn't working.

How do I make the 'p' element fit it's own content size inside a flex-container?

here's the code

```css
.hidden-box {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;

  gap: 1.5rem;

}

p {
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
        <div class="hidden-box">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur badipisicing elit. Dolorem
            nulla voluptatibus vel temporibus voluptates illo quaerat?
            Repudiandae eum exercitationem quisquam!
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: What exactly means _`inline-block` isn't working_? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: p tag is a block. No matter how many lines have. If you set 80%, the box of p has that width, but may have lots of lines. It's the expected result. If you set white-space: nowrap; style, then you have a single line but will exceed the 80%

Comment: @Jax-p I am trying to make 'p' size the '#text' size, but inside the flex-container.

Answer (score 1):

There is no display property for flex-item. Even you set them browser treat them as flex-item. **Solution:** Without that width & display property on p, it occupies its content width & align to center(Because of align-items: center property in flex-container)